# Como accedo a una id de la misma pagina

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este codigo.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Trabajo</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
      <th scope="col">Acción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
include("../../conexion.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM codigos";
$resultado = $conexion -> query($query);
while($row = $resultado -> fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['id'];?></th>
      <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Ver</a></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['fecha'];?></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Calificar</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"">Eliminar</a></td>

    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

quiero que al presionar "ver" aparezca un modal con el trabajo, pero para acceder al tabajo debo obtener el id de la fila donde se presiono y no se como obtenerlo.

se que hay formas de enviar el id hacia otra pagina pero quisiera hacerlo de esta forma
¿Es posible?

Comment: Lo puedes hacer usando ajax con javascript

Comment: @RimuruTempest Pues obviamente, pero **cómo** es lo que necesita *PacMan*.

Comment: @robe007 ya estaba preparando el ejemplo xd solo que me tarde por que estaba escribiendo desde mi movil

Comment: La respuesta que te da @Rimuru Tempest es lo mas parecido a lo que podria decirte, lo que agregaría es que quizá te falte agregar el js de bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lograr eso necesitas usar javascript con un petición vía ajax, para eso necesitaras hacer esto sin necesidad de crear múltiples archivos PHP

```
<?php
    require_once "../../conexion.php";
    // añadimos la conexion 
    $id = filter_var($_GET["id"], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    // filtramos la variable GET
    if (isset($id) && !empty($id)) {
    // verificamos que la variable GET no este vacío
    $result = [];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM codigos WHERE id LIKE '%{$id}%'";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    $result[] = $row;
    }
    return json_encode($result);
    } else {
    ?>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">Trabajo</th>
            <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
            <th scope="col">Acción</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM codigos";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
            while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['id'];?></th>
            <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
            <td><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn btn-success show-modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Ver</a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['fecha'];?></td>
            <td><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn btn-info">Calificar</a><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn btn-danger"">Eliminar</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
    }
    ?>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-success" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Ajax result </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="success" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
                //ajax success content here.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // hacemos la petición ajax al clickear el link con el class show-modal
    $(".show-modal").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    url: "/",
    data: { id: $(this).attr("data-id") },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
    // mostramos el modal
    $("#success").html(data);
    $("#modal-success").modal("show");
    }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: no sucede nada al presionar el boton, pense que era algo del modal pero probe con console.log y no manda nada, no se si hice algo mal

Comment: Te lo puse un poco mas fácil ;) edite el código que te muestro, intentalo de eso modo

Comment: No me sucede nada al apretar el boton ver aun asi :(

Comment: por lo que he visto la accion de apretar el boton la detecta bien. si pongo un console log en la funcion que manda a llamar el boton aparece bien pero cuando pongo un console log en success: function(data) no lo envia

Comment: Perdón tuve un pequeño error, ya lo corregí intenta de ese modo. El error estaba en `data: { id: $(this).attr("id") }` y en realidad era `data: { id: $(this).attr("data-id") }`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código podría ser un acercamiento a lo que buscas. Revísalo bien.

Loop en la tabla:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['id'];?></th>
    <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
    <td><a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-success" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Ver</a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['fecha'];?></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Calificar</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"">Eliminar</a></td>
</tr>
```

Código Js (Ajax):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'fetch_record.php', //Aquí se buscará el dato
            data :  'rowid='+ rowid, //Pasar el $id
            success : function(data){
            $('.fetched-data').html(data); //Mostrar los datos obtenidos de la BD
            }
        });
     });
});
```

La ventana modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Datos</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="fetched-data"></div> //Aquí se mostrará la data
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: el codigo ajax como lo implemento? nunca lo e usado